# Effeciently caching and updating the current date in a long-lived server application

Tags: java, performance

I have a long-lived server application that is designed to run with minimal downtime (e.g. 24/7 operation stopping only for maintenance). The application has to be able to handle thousands of requests a second, so performance is a concern.

To service each request. part of the application needs to know what the current date is (although not the time) and it must be stored in a `java.util.Date` object because of a 3rd party API.

However,`Date` objects are expensive to construct so creating a new one for each request doesn't sound sensible.

Sharing a `Date` object between requests and updating it once a day would mean only a single object would need to be created (per server worker thread) at startup, but then how can you update it in a safe manner?

For example, using a `ScheduledExecutorService` that runs just after midnight could increment the `Date`, but introduces Thread synchronisation into the mix: the `Date` object is now shared between the main thread and the thread that the `ScheduledExecutorService` spawns to run the update task.

Synchronising the 2 threads introduces another performance headache, due to the likelihood of contention on the shared resource between the thousands of requests being serviced (the single execution of the update thread per day is less of a concern because it only happens once per day, unlike the millions of requests we will service daily).

So, my question is **What is the most efficient way to ensure the application always knows what the current date is, even when running continuously for weeks on end?**

Comment: This sounds like a prime example of premature optimization. Thousands of requests a second is a joke, right? You can create millions, if not BILLIONS of new Dates a second...

Comment: That might be true, but creating Date objects isn't the only thing this application does, but seemed a potential issue to me given the received wisdom that creating Date objects is a relatively costly operation. For our use case, a millisecond improvement to average response times under load would be justified.

Comment: Your CPU can do a *lot* in a millisecond. In CPU time, one millisecond is an eternity. Avoiding the creation of a single Date will *not* save you that much. It will just take you a few minutes to benchmark how fast creating Dates is... why not try?

Comment: Actually after posting this I did write a a small test to further investigate the performance. I agree now that this is unnecessary, but as a hypothetical situation it's still interesting to know what approaches are possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chrisbunney, a couple of the answers on this thread have suggested using special-purpose concurrency classes, but if you really did need to cache a date as you originally asked, there's only one thing you need: the `volatile` keyword.

`AtomicReference` is good if you need an atomic check-and-swap operation, but in this case, you're not checking anything. You're just setting a reference to a new value, and you want that value to be visible to all threads. That's what `volatile` does.

If you were modifying the internal state of an existing object, then you might need locks. Or if you were going to read the value of the existing `Date`, do some calculations based on that, and generate a new `Date` object as a result, again some type of locking (or something like `AtomicReference`) would be necessary. But you're not doing that; again, you're only replacing a reference, with no regard to its previous value.

In general, if you have *only one* thread which ever replaces a value, and other threads only read the value, `volatile` is enough. No other concurrency control is needed. Or if you have multiple threads which can replace a value, but they only replace, not modify in-place, and they replace it with no regard for its previous value, then again, `volatile` is enough. Nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the expensive constructor your talking about is `new Date()`, which calls System.currentTimeMillis(). The easy way out would be to use `new Date(long)`, using the value stored in a `volatile` field. An external thread can then update this field at an appropriate time and the other threads will create their `Date` objects from this updated value.

Edit: while the current question may seem like a premature optimization, `System.currentTimeMillis()` can sometimes be the bottleneck. Check this link if you in that situation: http://dow.ngra.de/2008/10/27/when-systemcurrenttimemillis-is-too-slow/

Comment: Given that we'd never do a read-update-write type operation on the time field (when the day rolls, we'd just disregard the old value and overwrite it, and everything else is just reading the value), this seems a viable and clean approach

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with this optimization. It will have no measurable effect. A waste of time.

Comment: After writing some tests, I agree: on my local machine it takes about 0.0007 milliseconds to create each date. Although I'm still interested in this as a hypothetical situation.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html may avoid overhead of synchronization. If there is single thread executing the requests then you can execute a task on the same thread to update the date without having any synchronization overhead. If there are multiple threads then also same idea can be applied by making the date field thread local and updating it separately in each thread.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you to use the [caching feature from Google's Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). The caching library has good concurrency support, and it provides several alternative approaches to your problem.

One approach, if having a stale date is acceptable for your use case (e.g. for the first 100 seconds of a new day, it is all right if your app still thinks it's the previous day), you could use

```
LoadingCache<Object, Date> tDateCache 
    = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                  .maximumSize(1)
                  .expireAfterWrite(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                  .build( new CacheLoader<Object, Date>() {
                              public Date load(Object object) {
                                     return new Date();
                                     }
                              });
```

Access the cached date using `tDateCache.get(tDateCache)`. The `expireAfterWrite(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` parameter will cause your cache to be automatically refreshed every 100 seconds.

You could also have one monitor thread to automatically invoke `Cache.invalidateAll()` every time you detect the day is rolling, which will cause the load method of the cache loader to be re-invoked and a new date is created. No need to worry about concurrency, the library would handle that for you.